# Xamarin.Forms Button ContentLayout property not working as expected

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have added 4 buttons to a StackLayout and use the ContentLayout property to set the spacing between an image and the buttontext. When the image is placed next to the text the spacing is working as expected. But when i place the image above of below the text the spacing is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Buttons" x:Class="Buttons.MainPage">
    <StackLayout Padding="50">
        <Button ContentLayout="Right,50" Text="Sometext" Image="euro.png" HeightRequest="125" BackgroundColor="Teal" WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
        <Button ContentLayout="Left,50" Text="Sometext" Image="euro.png" HeightRequest="125" BackgroundColor="Teal" WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
        <Button ContentLayout="Top,50" Text="Sometext" Image="euro.png" HeightRequest="125" BackgroundColor="Teal" WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
        <Button ContentLayout="Bottom,50" Text="Sometext" Image="euro.png" HeightRequest="125" BackgroundColor="Teal" WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Attached a screenshot illustrating the problem. Does anyone have an idea what if and what i'm doing wrong?

[Screenshot 4 buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWS8R.png)

Comment: Hello! The problem is that the spacing is not between text and image, but between borders of button and content.
Just try to use another margins for cases when image is above or below the text.

Comment: I'm not sure how setting a margin would help and the Xamarin documentation is pretty clear stating that the spacing is between the image and text.

Comment: There are constant issues with that feature, there's an open one currently, maybe add a comment to make it a priority : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9227